# sklearn LDA: difference between coef_ and scalings_?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, linear-discriminant

I'm new to LDA. The documentation isn't very clear - what's the difference between coef_ and scalings_?

My data has many features (F1, F2, ..., F10000) and some labeled classes (C1, C2, ..., C5). I want to find the equations of the 2 lines (linear combinations of F1-F10000) that form the axes for the 2D space in which the classes (C1-C5) are maximally separated. How do I get the equations for these lines using sklearn?

Comment: maybe take a look at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/82497/can-the-scaling-values-in-a-linear-discriminant-analysis-lda-be-used-to-plot-e